# Does this block the rendering of my page?

Tags: php, background-process

At the beginning of the PHP that generates all the pages of my site is like

```
log_visitor_info(
    $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
    $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],
    $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
);
```

which calls the function

```
function log_visitor_info ( $ip, $pgurl, $refurl, $aginfo )
{
    global $wpdb, $ipsToIgnore; 
    if (!in_array($ip, $ipsToIgnore)) {
        $wpdb->insert('wp_nas_visits',  array(
            'ip'=>$ip,
            'refurl'=>$refurl,
            'pgurl'=>$pgurl,
            'aginfo'=>$aginfo
        ));
    }
}
```

where the `$wpdb->insert` is inserting something to the database. Because I don't need any of this info anywhere else in the page, I would prefer if it were possible to execute `log_visitor_info` asynchronously or "in the background", if you will. I think it's slowing down my page loads. Is there some way that I can put `log_visitor_info` on my server's queue that executes separately (if such a thing even exists ...) ? I have Windows Server 2012.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php execute a background process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45953/php-execute-a-background-process)

Comment: Can't you just get all of this from the server logs?

Comment: If not, look into an Ajax call on page load that will handle the logging

Comment: @RobGudgeon Yes, I can get this from server logs, but I have to write a script to parse the info out of them. Plus, this is for a website I want to be able to repackage with a custom analytics feature.

Comment: And yes, AJAX is a good idea, but can't I directly access the same vein of processing that an AJAX call would???

Comment: You could put it at the bottom of each page, for a quick win. Call flush() first to reduce blocking. Or you could fire something using exec() and tell it to redirect output so it doesn't cause the script to hang.

Comment: A parsing script wouldn't take much effort. I run done that aren't even code, just grep, sed, awk & pipes/redirects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not tested and I'm not a WordPress guy or fan, but should be adaptable if you want to use AJAX.  First, create a PHP page (logger.php) and add the following:

```
//include files needed to instantiate $wpdb

$ipsToIgnore  = unserialize($argv[1]);
$dataToInsert = unserialize($argv[2]);

if (!in_array($dataToInsert['ip'], $ipsToIgnore)) $wpdb->insert('wp_nas_visits', $dataToInsert);
```

Second, in the beginning of the PHP that generates all the pages of your site replace your function and function call with:

```
$ips  = escapeshellarg(serialize($ipsToIgnore));
$args = escapeshellarg(serialize(array('ip'     => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
                                       'pgurl'  => $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
                                       'refurl' => $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],
                                       'aginfo' => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])));

pclose(popen("start /B /path/to/php.exe /path/to/logger.php $ips $args", "r"));
```

You may need to `escapeshellarg()` the path to php.exe and the path to logger.php as well, especially if they have spaces in them.

Comment: See, but that's not something that can be included in a WordPress theme that can install itself.